# Please recommend a GUI telnet client

Tags: networking, software-rec, gui

I'm looking for a simple GUI telnet client. I only ever used the CLI one, simply named **`telnet`**.

Comment: Why? What would it do?

Comment: @matt I'm looking for the equivalent of the one that comes bundled with Windows. I want the GUIness of it all.

Comment: Concur with @matt. What "gui-ish" things do you want the GUI client do do that you can't get by running telnet in a terminal emulator?

Comment: @Shadur: I don't know. I just want to avoid having to go to the manpage to see how the thing works... the GUI factor :)

Comment: You realize we're going to have to revoke your unix geek license with that admission ;)

Comment: @Shadur: hehe, who says Unix is only for geeks.

Comment: What feature do you expect in a telnet GUI? As it stands, your question has too little information to be useful.

Comment: @Gilles: It should just do what telnet does, that's it. Nothing advanced. I wouldn't even guess that PuTTY could do it, although I wouldn't call it simple (it does so much).

Comment: Usage of telnet is strongly discouraged. Having said that, of course, there are some appliances out there which just speak telnet, and not ssh. Then use two xterms, one with telnet, one with man-telnet. Or xterm:telnet + firefox:telnet-help

Comment: @userunknown: ....or just one window GuI app that can do telnet, and no need for a manpage.

Comment: You still haven't explained what, precisely, you expect out of a 'gui telnet client' that PuTTY doesn't offer. Perhaps if you named the client you're using?

Comment: My *guess* is that when you say 'telnet client' you're actually referring to a MUD/MUSH client, and there I'll agree that there aren't that many good linux options. Gnoemoe got discontinued a while ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm baffled as to why you'd need one, but [PuTTY](http://www.tucows.com/preview/602074) comes with a linux client. It's open source, exists in the Debian repositories, and as an added bonus speaks SSH as well.

Comment: Putty can remember a list of hosts and ports. Something similar can be achieved with something like aliases in .bashrc or .zshrc, but it's a slightly smoother experience in Putty.

Comment: Putty would not be considered a "GUI" client.  Presumable, he likes a client with pull-down menus, changeable background from those of the WM, multiple font sizes, multiple tabs, etc. I do too.

Answer (score 1):

[PAC manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/) is a GUI based versatile telnet / SSH client allowing multi tabbed operation.